# problems with update manager after changing ubuntu version

Tags: apt, fonts

When I moved my desktop from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I got a problem: the  installation stopped displaying something about some microsoft font software. After that I succeeded to recover a correct boot and functioning for ubuntu 16.04 version except with update manager.
I get this error message " number of broken packages >0" I should have to run "sudo apt-get install -f" but it fails with the same message: problem with the same microsoft font software.

Comment: Please include the full output with the exact error message in your question.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-restricted-extras`should rectify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software Centre and install Synaptics Package Manager. After installing open it and select `Custom Filters` from the bottom left and from the left toolbar select `Broken`. Right Click on the broken packages and select reinstallation or complete removal option. This should solve it.